# Last occurence of element in a list in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

Assuming `l` is a list and `elem` is an element, how can I return the last occurence of the element `elem` in the list `l`? Also return -1 if the element does not exisit in `l`. I don't quite understand how to use recursion for iterating through the list...

```
let rec getLastOccurence l elem = …
```

Comment: do you mean "index of" the last occurrence? because otherwise the return values (the element and -1) are not the same type

Answer (score 3):

```
let findi x l = 
  let rec loop i n l = 
    match l with 
    | y::tl -> loop (i+1) (if y = x then i else n) tl 
    | [] -> n 
  in 
  loop 0 (-1) l;;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need two accumulators to keep track of the current index and the maximum index found for the element. Then you just recurse to the end of the list and return the "maximum index" value.

```
let rindex elem = 
  let rec find_index i max_found = function
    | (x::xs) when x = elem -> find_index (i+1) i xs
    | (_::xs) -> find_index (i+1) max_found xs
    | [] -> max_found
  in find_index 0 (-1);;
```

This can also be expressed pretty simply as a fold:

```
let rindex elem ls = 
  let find_index (i, max) elem' = (i+1, if elem' = elem then i else max)
  in snd (fold_left find_index (0, -1) ls);;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tail recursive algorithm for finding an integer in a list:

```
let find_index elt lst =
  (* Wrap inner function that accepts an accumulator to keep the interface clean *)
  let rec find_it elt acc = function
    | hd :: tl when elt = hd -> acc (* match *)
    | hd :: tl -> find_it elt (acc + 1) tl (* non-match *)
    | _ -> raise Not_found (* end of list *)
  in find_it elt 0 lst (* call inner function with accumulator starting at 0 *)
;;
```

Comment: I dont understand the line | _ -> raise Not_found

Comment: The first two match options catch the case when there is a head and tail element, using the cons operator (::). The _ symbol is a convention saying, "Ignore this match."  The pattern matches anything, but since the first two catch everything from a :: b to  a :: nothing, the last one is used to catch the situation where we have iterated through the entire list and not found a match. Re-reading your question, you want to change "raise Not_found" to -1.

Comment: Note that you could also use "| [] -> raise Not_found" for the final pattern. Neither would bind to a variable. They are effectively equivalent.

Comment: This will find the first index. Polly appears to be looking for the last index. Though you could just do this on `(List.rev lst)` to get the offset from the end of the list.

Comment: Ah, she wanted the *last* occurrence. Self-downmod for not reading the assignment carefully :)

Answer (score 0):

Late addition, but if you need to iterate over a list with an accumulator (though in this case it needs to hold *two* pieces of information) then this lends itself quite naturally to `List.fold_left`.

```
let find_last_index elt lst =
  List.fold_left 
    (fun (i, last) x -> if x = elt then (i+1, i) else (i+1, last)) 
    (0, 0) 
    lst 
  |> snd
```

```
# find_last_index 2 [1; 2; 4; 2; 8; 2; 0];;
- : int = 5
```

As we iterate over the list, we'll keep track of the current index `i` and the `last` index for any elements that equal `elt`. In the event `x` does equal `elt`, we update the `last` value. Finally, both accumulators are returned as a tuple, and we select the second.

This only works if `elt` actually is in the list. If it isn't, we can handle that by either returning `-1` or by returning an `int option` value.

```
let find_last_index elt lst =
  List.fold_left 
    (fun (i, last) x -> if x = elt then (i+1, i) else (i+1, last)) 
    (0, -1) 
    lst 
  |> snd
```

Or:

```
let find_last_index elt lst =
  List.fold_left 
    (fun (i, last) x -> if x = elt then (i+1, Some i) else (i+1, last)) 
    (0, None) 
    lst 
  |> snd
```